# Is it normal that CPU usage exceeds 100% using dispatch async in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, infinite-loop, blockingqueue

I'm a beginner in swift 2, and I'm trying to make my program blocks while showing only a progress spinner until some operation finishes, I made that code snippet in a button with the action "touch up inside", my problem is that while debugging,Xcode 7 CPU usage jumps to 190 % once I tap my button and keeps high until the flag changes its value, Is it normal that CPU usage jumps like that?, also Is it a good practice to use the following snippet or shud i use sleep or some other mechanism inside my infinite loop?

```
let queue2 = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
            dispatch_async(self.queue2) { () -> Void in
            while(flag == true)
            {
                //wait until flag sets to false from previous func
            }
            self.dispatch_main({ 

                 //continue after the flag became false
})
```

Comment: It's a horrible practice. Simply never use loops to wait for something, let your *some operation* notify when it's finished and use a completion handler.

Comment: actually i was writing C for 5 years, am trying to achieve my logic with little similar syntax, can i call sleep inside my loop to decrease the cpu usage?, i read about nsoperation but am not that familiar with its syntax

Comment: to extend vadian's comment: This (anti-) pattern is usually referred to as "[busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)" and it is a great way to discharge your device's battery quickly.

Comment: I wrote an answer with a short example how to use a completion handler.

Comment: Sleeping inside the loop would decrease the cpu usage but you still shouldn't do it.

Comment: Busy waiting in C is just as appallingly terrible practice as it is in Swift as it is in any language.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very economical completion handler

```
func test(completion:() -> ())
{
  // do hard work
  completion()
}

let queue2 = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue2) {
  test() {
    print("completed")
  }
}
```

or with additional dispatch to the main queue to update the UI

```
let queue2 = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue2) {
  test() {
    print("completed")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      // update UI
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm reading data from server and i want to wait until Done flag is set to true, in this wait interval, only a progress bar is showing in the screen and no UI update until done == true, how to achieve this with the code snippet above

Comment: A progress bar is also UI ;-) - start the animation before the `test()` call and stop it instead of printing `completed`.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally wrong approach as you are using while loop for waiting. You should use [Completion Handler](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corespotlight/cssearchquery/1649312-completionhandler) to achieve this kind of stuff.

> Completion handlers are callbacks that allow a client to perform some action when a framework method or function completes its task. Often the client uses a completion handler to free state or update the user interface. Several framework methods let you implement completion handlers as blocks (instead of, say, delegation methods or notification handlers).

Refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a sort of class which manages these "some operation finishes".

When you finish your operations you can comunicate by completion handler or delegation. In the meanwhile you can disable the user interaction of your UI until the end of these operations.

If you provide more informations about your background operations I can add some snippets of code.